# Reinstall Ubuntu option is disabled

Tags: system-installation, reinstall, reinstalling

I have a Ubuntu and Windows on my machine and I have to reinstall Ubuntu without losing any of my data, /home folder, but reinstall ubuntu option is grayed out for some reason.

What should I do in order to reinstall it without losing files and programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can click on "Something Else" and then manually reinstall it. Choose the same paritions for the same mounts you had before such as /home and root (/) and just make sure the format checkbox is NOT checked. It will reinstall overtop of everything (overwrite) but won't delete anything. Of course as always, you should backup your /home folder before, just in case

Comment: how to know which is the boot partition when having for example `/dev/nvme0n1` (seems the whole disk), `/dev/nvme0n1p1`(fat32) and `/dev/nvme0p2` (ext2)? It is asking foe the `Device for boot loader installation`

Comment: The boot partition can't be fat32 so it is the other one.