# Ubuntu reinstalltion asking for boot loader installation

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation, boot-partition

Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/790250/654519) on how to reinstall ubuntu without loosing data when the `reinstall ubuntu` option is not directly available, when selecting `Something else`, it asks to select the `Device for boot loader installation`. The options are:

- `/dev/nvme0n1` the whole disk,
- `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, with filesystem `fat32`
  `/dev/nvme0n1p11, with filesystem`ext2`.

`/dev/sda` is the ubuntu live installation media.

Which partition should be selected?

Here an image:

**EDIT**
The disk is encrypted and booting is corrupted, i.e., it does not boot anymore.
Autoselection for boot selection seems to be `nvme0n1` but when I click on `Install Now`, a window appears saying: `No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partition menu.

[image]

Comment: Does it really ask to select the device, or does it auto-selects, but provides other options as well?

Comment: Please see the edit. Autoselection seems to be `nvme0n1` but when I do it a window appears saying: `No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partition menu. Further note I forgot: the disk was encrypted.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to identify the partition to be selected?

Comment: With UEFI it does not matter what you select. It automatically installs boot loader into first drive's ESP - efi system partition. Whether UEFI or BIOS you almost always select drive, never partition. If / (root) device not selected, have you decrypted your install, so it can see /? And if separate /boot partition, you must also select it. If issue is just not booting, may be better to resolve that with Boot-Repair or fsck on ext4 partition(s). You do have good backups? If you select format, it will erase old install.

Comment: As implied above, there is not need to select where to install grub, unless there are reasons for that. You should worry about decrypting the root partition, and then designating it as such to the installer.

Comment: @oldfred for the backup, I managed to decrypt the disk and copy all my home folder which seems to be intact. After decrypting the disk many selections for `Device for boot loader installation` are available: `/dev/mapper/luks...`, `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root-root`, `/dev/nvme0n1`, `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, `/dev/nvme0n1p2`, `/dev/dm-0`. I do not have `/` as option though

Comment: Although, may I suggest you tape a small note inside battery compartment or on the back of the desktop chassis which states where the boot loader is placed? If you have problems later, it's handy to know.

Comment: @K7AAY Well, with the wisdom of hindsight, yes you can :)

Comment: Your screen shot above showed an ESP as p1 FAT32, a typical /boot as ext2 formatted as p2 and p3 as the entire install using LVM - logical volumes.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/nvme0n1p1` is the UEFI system partition, so:

1. ensure legacy is turned off in the UEFI firmware
2. **Do not encrypt** that partition
3. install the boot loader there